# Xamarin with MSAL cannot save access token as Keychain Access Groups changed during Ad-Hoc provisioning

Tags: ios, azure-active-directory, keychain, adal, azure-ad-msal

We have added the latest MSAL library to our Xamarin project and added the Keychain sharing capabilities to the entitlements plist:

[image]

The app builds ok on a developer machine and the app authenticates correctly against Azure AD B2C.

When we build through ADO and publish in App Center (Ad-Hoc provisioning) the app builds, and the appears to authenticate against the Azure AD B2C, but does not communicate with our other Azure resources (API, Storage, etc.)  It appears that the Keychain access group is not found and whilst the authentication takes place normally MSAL fails to save the access token in the Key Chain.

```
iOSTokenCacheAccessor.Save (System.String account, System.String service, System.String generic, System.Int32 type, System.String value)
```

`Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException: The application does not have keychain access groups enabled in the Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to the iOS keychain`.

We think this is because during Ad-Hoc provisioning the app is re-signed after the device id has been included in the provisioning profile but the Ad-Hoc profile entitlements section only contain the [app id].* not the com.microsoft.adalcache value.

1. Does the entitlements.plist get merged during build into the profile, i.e., Keychain Groups added to the entitlements section of the plist?
2. If so, what does this and when does it happen in the build pipeline?
3. How does Ad-Hoc provisioning work with this scenario?

Any help really appreciated as this is currently blocking our release.

Comment: could you open an issue in the [MSAL repo](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues) and link to this post? Thank you.

Comment: MSAL .NET forces you to provide a teamId, which will change between dogfood and development. Opening an issue in MSAL will allow us to track the issue and keep you updated on a fix. MSAL would need to resolve teamId itself.

Comment: In order to use the same app signed with different apple dev accounts, you need to use $(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache

Comment: Jenny, thanks for the comments.  It does look like this is an issue with App Center changing the entitlements when ad-hoc provisioning is used (i.e., asking App Center to automatically manage device ids).  Currently we are blocked and resorting to removing the MSAL library unless we can discover a workaround or fix.

Comment: Have added a bug to GitHub as requested: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/783

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MSAL 2.7.0](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/releases/tag/2.7.0), MSAL now resolves the TeamId at runtime. A new property `iOSKeychainSecurityGroup` should be used instead of `KeychainSecurityGroup`. More information can be found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Xamarin-ios-specificities#use-ioskeychainsecuritygroup-property). There was also a bug in AppCenter where they were using a wildcard in the Entitlements when they re-signed the app. This has been fixed as of 1/21.