# Xamarin forms ios - b2c authentication works in simulator but not in device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

Based in this sample https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native.git

Android works, and ios simulator as well

But in iphone device(tested in 2) i get this exception

The application does not have keychain access groups enabled in the Entitlements.plist. As a result, there was a failure to save to the iOS keychain. The keychain access group '*******.com.microsoft.adalcache' is not enabled in the Entitlements.plist. Also, use the WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup api to set the keychain access group. See https://aka.ms/msal-net-enable-keychain-groups for more details on enabling keychain access groups and entitlements.

Same sign profile and certificate

Edit: Entitlements.plist

```
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
    <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

pcaBuilder:

```
 var builder = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(B2CConstants.ClientID)
                .WithB2CAuthority(B2CConstants.AuthoritySignInSignUp)
                .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(B2CConstants.IOSKeyChainGroup)
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{B2CConstants.ClientID}://auth");
```

Constants:

```
public static string IOSKeyChainGroup = "com.microsoft.adalcache";
```

Custom Entitlements: selected Entitlements.plist

Comment: That seems like a very explicit exception message that explains what the problem is

Comment: You right, so the question is why simulator works?

Comment: Apple enforces more restrictions when testing on a device

Comment: Any clue? i am stucked

Comment: this is explicitly addressed in the docs - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native#ios-specific-considerations

Comment: i double cheked everything, google about, and still stucked

Comment: Thanks @gilberto and let me know if these documents will help - https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/iOS-Keychain-Access and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53829119/xamarin-with-msal-cannot-save-access-token-as-keychain-access-groups-changed-dur

Comment: Thanks, it does not help, actually even the sample throw the same exception in my device. Could be related with sign process?

Comment: You could look at [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/issues/783),maybe it will help you.

Comment: Thnaks guys, everything works on visual studio for mac, reinstalling vs windows